# Spectral mapping theorem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Rudin's book contains in chapter 10 a spectral mapping theorem for (self-adjoint) unbounded operators that respects the point-spectrum, in the sense that he shows $f(\sigma_p(T))=\sigma_p(f(T))$ for nowhere constant holmorphic functions $f.$

I would like to know if this result is still true for the $ac$ and $sc$ spectrum (maybe under stronger assumptions on $f$). In particular, I am curious about the relationship between self-adjoint operators $T$ and $T^2$

Comment: Yes, this works for such functions. Just use that if $T$ is multiplication by $t$ in $L^2(\mathbb R, d\rho)$ (or a sum of such spaces; spectral theorem), then $f(T)$ is multiplication by $f(t)$. Moreover, $f$ will map null sets to null sets and countable sets to countable sets.